# BigQuery: How to set IAM condition to delete table (using CEL?)

Tags: google-bigquery, conditional-statements, identity-management

In Google BigQuery, I want to restrict an assigend role for table delete action, so that users only can delete tables they created themselves.
I assume, that it's (only?) possible with Condition Editor using CEL expressions (see https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#cel).

Since I'm not familiar with CEL, I ask for some hints how to write a condition like

- resource.creator == current_user

But I have no clue about the syntax, the available CEL variables and how to reference them.
[image]

Condition Builder doesn't provide user details, does it?
[image]